# mongodb query on nodeJS say cannot read property remove of 'null'

Tags: node.js, mongodb

This is my entry in database in mongodb which is of type object in schema

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5539bed4b417d75d1fee5df7"),
    "favMovies" : {
        "alternate_ids" : {
            "imdb" : "2820852"
        },
        "studio" : "Universal Pictures",
        "abridged_directors" : [
            {
                "name" : "James Wan"
            }
        ],
        "abridged_cast" : [
            {
                "characters" : [
                    "Dominic Toretto"
                ],
                "id" : "162652472",
                "name" : "Vin Diesel"
            },
            {
                "characters" : [
                    "Brian O'Conner"
                ],
                "id" : "162654234",
                "name" : "Paul Walker"
            },
            {
                "characters" : [
                    "Louie Tran"
                ],
                "id" : "162684066",
                "name" : "Tony Jaa"
            },
            {
                "characters" : [
                    "Deckard Shaw"
                ],
                "id" : "162653720",
                "name" : "Jason Statham"
            },
            {
                "characters" : [
                    "Luke Hobbs"
                ],
                "id" : "770893686",
                "name" : "Dwayne \"The Rock\" Johnson"
            }
        ],
        "synopsis" : "Continuing the global exploits in the unstoppable franchise built on speed, Vin Diesel, Paul Walker and Dwayne Johnson lead the returning cast of Fast & Furious 7. James Wan directs this chapter of the hugely successful series that also welcomes back favorites Michelle Rodriguez, Jordana Brewster, Tyrese Gibson, Chris \"Ludacris\" Bridges, Elsa Pataky and Lucas Black. They are joined by international action stars new to the franchise including Jason Statham, Djimon Hounsou, Tony Jaa, Ronda Rousey and Kurt Russell.",
        "ratings" : {
            "audience_score" : 88,
            "audience_rating" : "Upright",
            "critics_score" : 82,
            "critics_rating" : "Certified Fresh"
        },
        "release_dates" : {
            "theater" : "2015-04-03"
        },
        "critics_consensus" : "",
        "runtime" : 140,
        "mpaa_rating" : "PG-13",
        "genres" : [
            "Mystery & Suspense",
            "Action & Adventure"
        ],
        "year" : 2015,
        "title" : "Furious 7",
        "id" : 771354922
    },
    "username" : "punk",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

In my Node JS code I use the following query

```
app.delete('/favMovies/:user/:movid',function(req, res){
    var user = req.params.user;
    var mid = req.params.movid;
    console.log(mid);
    console.log(user);

    MovModel.find({username:user,'favMovies.id':mid}, function (err, doc) {
    doc.remove();
    MovModel.find({username: user},function (err, data) {         
        res.json(data);
    });
    });
});
```

In the above snippet mid is movie id. For the above entry in database mov 
"id" : 771354922
and user is username but I am getting following error for my query which is working fine in mongo client.

```
/Users/pankajtripathi/Documents/ECLIPSE-FILES/MyProject/server.js:132
    doc.remove();
       ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of null
    at /Users/pankajtripathi/Documents/ECLIPSE-FILES/MyProject/server.js:132:5
    at /Users/pankajtripathi/Documents/ECLIPSE-FILES/MyProject/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1169:16
    at /Users/pankajtripathi/Documents/ECLIPSE-FILES/MyProject/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/kareem/index.js:103:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

Comment: change that line to `if(doc) doc.remove();`

Comment: Null in the result means your query returned no results.
And if you want to find and remove, why don't you use findOneAndRemove instead ?

Comment: Where is angularJS coming into picture here?

Answer (score 0):

You should use findOneAndRemove()

```
MovModel.findOneAndRemove({username:user,'favMovies.id':mid}, function (err, doc) {
if (err) console.log(err);
res.json(doc);
}
```

> Finds a matching document, removes it, passing the found document (if
>   any) to the callback. Executes immediately if callback is passed.

Comment: It is not working. When I have two movies and I click on anyone to delete the res.json(doc) is returned as null.... I want the response to be remaining movies in the database

Comment: try taking the quotes off of favMovies.  If you are getting null the query is coming back empty.  It isn't finding anything.

Comment: But if you want all an updated list, just put MovModel.find({username: user},function (err, data) {         
        res.json(data);
    });
inside the callback for the findOneAndRemove query.

Comment: I added MovModel.find in the callback..but the res.json(data) is sending all the movie results as it is. Which means it is not removing the record from DB

Comment: Are there multiple movie entries inside each user record?

Comment: This is what i added    MovModel.findOneAndRemove({username:user,'favMovies.id':mid}, function (err, doc) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  MovModel.find({username: user} ,function (err, data) {
      res.json(data);
  });
 });

Comment: MovModel has schema as {username: String, favMovie: Object}.....so there can be multiple movies for a single user in the collection

Comment: You aren't going to be able to remove one movie from the record.  Mongo doesnt support deep modification.  You have to update the whole record.

Comment: in the collection or in the record?

Comment: the query that I have stated in my question was working fine earlier but today I made a slight change in my angularJS controller and it is giving me error

Comment: You said: In the above snippet mid is movie id. For the above entry in database mov "id" : 771354922 and user is username but I am getting following error for my query which is working fine in mongo client.

if it is returning user as 'username' that is why your query is returning empty.  The username is 'punk'.

If that is the case and it is supposed to be 'punk' but somehow 'username' is getting in there, check your ajax call in angular and check your bindings.

Comment: it is taking username as punk from angularJS as I checked it in my nodeJS server

Comment: can you try just doing 
MovModel.remove({username:user,'favMovies.id':mid}, function (err, doc) {
if (err) console.log(err);
MovModel.find({username: user} ,function (err, data) {     res.json(data); }); });

Answer (score 0):

I changed the query and its working fine now.

```
MovModel.findOneAndRemove({username:user,_id:mid}, function (err, doc) {
console.log(doc);
MovModel.find({username: user},function (err, data) {       
    res.json(data);
});
});
```

Comment: It looks like you were passing the wrong thing in the id param.  That's why your queries were coming back null.

Comment: if you plan on accepting your own answer then I will delete mine.
Also, you should still consider moving the find inside the callback to make sure they get processed in the correct order.  Mongodb is completely synchronous so the two queries should just hit mongo's que, but something weird could go wrong there and it may look like your delete doesn't go through, when it actually did.